# PhoneGap FileAPI Error Code 5 finding video in storage/emulated

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Just getting started with PhoneGap File API / Cordova 3.0 and I have a little issue looking up a file 
using getFile(). Don't know if the chaining is wrong. Or just missing the obvious...

I get to gotFS, passing in the full path as file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/... and the result is an error 5. I am guessing the path is not correct, or I can't get to storage/emulated?

The whole point is to return the file as a base64-encoded data URL e.g.,readAsDataURL.

```
// I just finished taking a video
// 
function captureSuccess(mediaFile) {
    // Store the results
    //
    window.media = mediaFile;

    // Get started with the file request
    //
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);


    function gotFS(fileSystem) {

        // Get the path of the file
        // Will return something like //file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/....
        //
        var fullPath = window.media[0].fullPath;

        // Let's try and resolve, make sure I'm not crazy. I might be.
        //
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fullPath, winConvert, failConvert);


        function winConvert(uri){

          // The resolve matches file location stored at window.media
          //
          console.log(uri);

        }

        function failConvert(error){

          console.log('Something happend resolving uri: '+error.code);

        }


    fileSystem.root.getFile(fullPath, null, gotFileEntry, fail);

    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {

         console.log('gotFileEntry');

        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);

    }                  


    function gotFile(file){

        console.log('gotFile');

        readDataUrl(file);

    }  

    function readDataUrl(file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

            console.log(evt.target.result);

        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

    function fail(error) {

        console.log(error.code);


    }

}
```

Comment: I did not solve this... had help from a very good friend! It was the path... needed to split the root from the window.media. So you'd get DCIM/Camera/.... as opposed to file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/.... Oh, what a silly mistake.

Comment: Harrison, thank you so much for posting this comment! I'm trying this now. I'm doing $cordovaCamera.getPicture, and I get file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<myclasspath>/cache/<somenumber>.jpg What should I strip out in all cases? So I need to edit the fullPath var in gotFS?