# Check if file exists in device with Phonegap

Tags: ios, file, cordova

Completely related to [How to check a file's existence in phone directory with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294166/how-to-check-a-files-existence-in-phone-directory-with-phonegap),

This is what I have in Android 4.0.4:

```
function checkIfFileExists(path, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist) {
    var getFSSuccess = function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
    };
    var getFSFail = function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    };
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFSSuccess, getFSFail); //of requestFileSystem
};
```

`fileExists` and `fileDoesNotExist` are basically alerts so I know what is happening.

What is happening is that even if the file exists, `fileDoesNotExist` is being executed.

`path` is something like "file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/14112312312.jpg", and the error I am getting is `ENCODING_ERR`.

UPDATE: Removing "file://" from the name worked. I added, at the beginning of `getFSSuccess`,

```
if (path.indexOf("file://") > -1) {
    path = path.substring(7, path.length);
}
```

and that solved the problem.

Question is: why and what would be the solution for iOS? I am updating  tag's src attribute with the full name ("file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/14112312312.jpg") and works perfect...

UPDATE: If the file is a video, the fix doesn't work. Should I remove everything before DCIM folder?

Totally related to [PhoneGap FileAPI Error Code 5 finding video in storage/emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508894/phonegap-fileapi-error-code-5-finding-video-in-storage-emulated) I think.

UPDATE: Looks like this

```
if (isAndroid() && path.indexOf("file://") > -1) {
    path = path.substring(7, path.length);
} else if (isAndroid() && path.indexOf("file:") > -1) {
    path = path.substring(5, path.length);
}
```

solved the problem. But my question is, still, why? And, would I need to do something similar for iOS?

Comment: Would've been awesome if you could answer your own question with the fully working function for checking if file exists. Been looking for days for this.

Comment: I have not an answer for this. We decided to allow only images and to apply this function : function checkIfFileExists(url,callBackFunc) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = function() { callBackFunc(true); };
  img.onerror = function() { callBackFunc(false); };
  img.src = url;
 };.

Comment: I found another way to check if file exists today that are pretty similar. I used it in the code in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442234/set-custom-attribute-for-autodividers