# Set custom attribute for autodividers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to divide a ListView that is dynamically populated in jQuery-mobile. I am setting some listitems with attribute `status="true"` and some to `status="false"`, and wonder if it's possible to automatically divide these into two groups (Downloaded/Not downloaded)?

This is my HTML:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">
    <div>
        <ul id="linkList" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var $li;
var $status = 'false';

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileSource + val.title + ".pdf", success, fail);

// if file exists
function success() {
    $li.find("a").on("click", function(){ openPdf(val.title); });
    $status = 'true';
}

// if file doesnt exists
function fail() {
    $li.find("a").on("click", function(){ downloadPdf(val.title,val.url); });
    $status = 'false';
}

$li = $("<li><a href='#' status=''+status+''>"+val.title+"</a></li>");

$("#linkList").append($li).listview('refresh');
$("#linkList").listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
    var out = li.attr('status');
    return out;
    }
}).listview('refresh');
```

So, is it possible to do this automatically, or do I have to do the sorting by code, and add the dividers. The code as it is doesn't add any dividers at all.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: @AtanuCSE No dividers are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, autodividers really only works if your list is already sorted by status.  So you will want to sort it before adding it to the UL.

Next, for status you can use a data-attribute on the LI or the anchor within the li:

```
'<li ><a href="#" data-status="' + item.status +'">' + item.val + '</a></li>'
```

Then when adding the items, set the autodividersSelector to retrieve the data-attribute on the anchor:

```
$('#linkList')
    .empty()
    .append(allfiles)
    .listview({
        autodividers:true,
        autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
            var out = li.find('a').data("status");
            return out;
        }
    })
    .listview("refresh");
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0kxb8z38/)**

Comment: So, if I understand correctly. This will not work if the downloaded and not downloaded are saved in grouped order?

Comment: @janlindso, if you do not sort, you will end up with multiple groups instead of just 2: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0kxb8z38/1/